# How to store different but same type of values into a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I just came across this issue and I'm not too sure how to approach it. Let say I have 2 types of values as such, it's currently being stored in R as each independent value.
[image]

How can I create a dataframe where I can get something like:

```
Value_Number      Type      Value
     01            A          1
     02            A          1
     03            A          1
     04            A          1
     05            A          1
     01            B          1
     02            B          2
     03            B          3
     04            B          4
     05            B          5
```

Comment: Are you sure you wrote that `Value` column correctly? In any case, you might look at `tidyr::separate()`.

Comment: Try `read.table(text = sub("^Value([A-Z])_(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)", "\\1 \\2 \\3", str1), header = FALSE)`

Comment: I just made up the column as those values are located in the environment as independent values instead of in a dataframe or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution.

- First, I create the initial data.
- Next, I create a data frame from these data based on their names.

  - I list the variables' names by searching for the pattern `"Value"` (`ls(pattern = "Value")`).
  - I also pull their values using `get`.
- Then, I load the libraries for `dplyr` and `tidyr`.
- I split `Value_Number` into two and put the resulting values in `Type` and `Value_Number`.
- Finally, I strip `Value` off the front of each `Type` using `sub`.

```r
# Initial data 
ValueA_01 <- 1
ValueA_02 <- 2
ValueA_03 <- 3
ValueA_04 <- 4
ValueA_05 <- 5
ValueB_01 <- 1
ValueB_02 <- 2
ValueB_03 <- 3
ValueB_04 <- 4
ValueB_05 <- 5

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(Value_Number = ls(pattern = "Value"), 
                 Value = unlist(lapply(ls(pattern = "Value"), get)))

# Load library
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

# Separate
df %<>% 
  separate(Value_Number, c("Type", "Value_Number")) %>% 
  mutate(Type = sub("Value", "", Type))
#>    Type Value_Number Value
#> 1     A           01     1
#> 2     A           02     2
#> 3     A           03     3
#> 4     A           04     4
#> 5     A           05     5
#> 6     B           01     1
#> 7     B           02     2
#> 8     B           03     3
#> 9     B           04     4
#> 10    B           05     5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made myself clear in the original question that the values are separated from the name of the values.

Comment: @cheklapkok Your question isn't clear. Can you clarify exactly what you want?

Comment: I just attached a picture of the environment.

Comment: @cheklapkok So, that is a single column in a data frame called `Values`?

Comment: no, they are not. It's just a bunch of values in the environment

Comment: Yes, however the ```df``` that was created only has 2 variables which are ```Value_Number``` and ```Value```. It's weird that it's different than what the code shown. Do you know why?

Comment: @cheklapkok You'd need to store the result somewhere. See update with `magrittr` compound assignment pipe for storing the result.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for being here the whole time. I really appreciate your help. @Lyngbakr